# Is there a method or event when tooltip is going to be displayed?

Tags: cocoa, tooltip, nsview

I want tooltip to display the coordinates in an NSView.  I thought if there was something akin to toolTipWillBeDisplayed that might be called just prior to displaying the tooltip, I could have a method to set the tooltip string to the coordinate the mouse was hovering over.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be a method/event before a tooltip is displayed.

> Any ideas or suggestions?

You can consider replacing the `NSView` method `- (NSToolTipTag)addToolTipRect:owner:userData:` using *method swizzling*. Your replacement method would need to call the original method passing in your own `owner` and `userData` with the latter being the original `owner` & `userData`. Your `owner` object would implement `- (NSString *) view:stringForToolTip:point:userData:` to provide the tooltip by (a) using the original `owner` & `userData` to obtain the string and (b) adding the value passed as `point`.

If you get stuck implementing this ask another question showing what you've written, stating what doesn't work, etc. and someone will probably help you along. If you've never heard of method swizzling you'll find details on it by searching.

HTH